# Walking in front of someone saying kaddish

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kaddish, kavana-concentration, issur-vheter

I have heard that in addition to the prohibition of passing in front of someone who is davening shemoneh esrei, it is also forbidden (or at least improper) to walk in front of someone who is saying kaddish. Does anyone know if this is true, and if so what the source is? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[*Birkei Yosef*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai) ([OC 56:9](https://books.google.com/books?id=KrjXAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA79&lpg=RA2-PA79&dq=%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%9D+%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8+%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8+%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%93&source=bl&ots=GiQv0rR0V4&sig=6bzK_Yh1U1AaFkEVSpaEFTmZTxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjun9_3u6HZAhXI7IMKHUp5BkUQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%93&f=false)) equates passing in front of one who is saying *Kaddish* with passing in front of one who is *davening* the Amidah. He is quoted by the *Ben Ish Chai* ([*Vayechi 1, 10*](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%97%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99#%D7%99)), and *Sha'arei Teshuvah* ([OC 56:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'arei_Teshuvah_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.56?lang=bi)).

*Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef* ([56:9](http://www.yahadoot.net/item.asp?id=897&cid=16)) brings this, as well as that some disagree.

Answer (score 1):

From [halachipedia.com](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kaddish)

> Just like one does not walk in front of someone who is praying, so too
>   one should not walk in front of someone who is reciting Kaddish.
>   (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch of Rav Rephael Baruch Toledano, siman 12, laws
>   of kaddish, seif 2; Ben Ish Chai (Vayechi, 10)

Comment: Do they explain why that should be?

Comment: On halachapedia, a reason is not given. I don't have the actual sefer to check for more details

Comment: @DoubleAA No reason is given, other than "Just like one does not walk in front of someone who is praying".

Comment: @ploni how's that for circular logic

Comment: @DoubleAA Agreed, but that's all that the sources say...

Comment: @ploni maybe a נראה לי or something? Anything to indicate they are just making it up as opposed to quoting earlier sources or a common tradition?

Comment: @DoubleAA The earliest source that I know of is the Birkei Yosef, who is quoting from a תשובה כת"י, which was never published.