# Walking in front of a Muslim who is praying

Tags: tefilla, gentiles

There are a number of questions on Mi Yodeya dealing with the halachos (laws) of walking in front of a Jew who is praying, for instance
[When you're trapped by someone Davening behind you](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/when-youre-trapped-by-someone-davening-behind-you?noredirect=1&lq=1)

There is also a question dealing with walking in front of someone who is saying Kaddish.
[Walking in front of someone saying kaddish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89264/walking-in-front-of-someone-saying-kaddish)

Is there any notion of not walking in front of a Muslim who is praying? (An acquaintance made this claim but I have never heard of any source for anything like this.)

Comment: Are you asking about Muslims specifically or about any non-Jew who is praying?

Comment: I was asking specifically about Muslims. (As far as I am aware, the Muslim concept of Hashem is identical to, or extremely close to, the Jewish concept of Hashem). Certainly if the answer to my question is "Yes" then a question about non-Jews would be a follow-up question!

Comment: I dont believe our def of אחד is identical to them,see the Rambams def

Comment: To VTCers: This question does not require knowledge of Islam to answer this question and therefore does not fall under the comparative religion rubric.

Comment: Does walking in front of him disturb his concentration? Is there a concept that a Muslim praying is connected to the shechina and walking between them would disrupt that? These are the reasons given to not walk in front of a Jew who is praying. I think according to the first reason this question would in fact be off topic. The second reason seems on topic. @DonielF

Answer (score 5):

There are suggestions that the Rabbi Yehoshua Leib Diskin held that one should not walk in front of a Muslim who is praying.

This is mentioned for example in the penultimate paragraph [here](https://din.org.il/2014/06/10/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%94/), saying that God's presence is in front of them.

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be important for Muslims that people do not wall in front of them while they pray, for their own religious reasons. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutrah

Maybe the notion you are hearing of comes from respecting this.